# Data is not inserting into table?

Tags: php, mysql

GYZ i dont know why data is not inserting in my data base #Mysql
. infact im using mysqli_connect and mysql_connect both ,I'm still facing same prob ..this is my code:

[image]

```
<?php 
   $servername = 'localhost';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';  
   $db='school'; 
   @mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password); 

   @mysqli_select_db($db); //or die ('not Connect to db '); 
   if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { 
     $sid= $_GET['sid']; 
     $sname= $_GET['sname']; 
     $fname= $_GET['fname'];
     $order= @mysqli_query("insert into school (sid,sname,fname) values ('$sid','$sname','$fname');"); 
      if ($order) { 
        echo '<br>Input data is successful';
     } else {
        echo '<br>Input data is not valid'; 
     } 
  } ?>
```

Comment: Instead of posting images, post your code here.

Comment: simple simple answer................. RTMs! you didn't do something important

Comment: what  i didnt understand what u said ?

Comment: ..............as in pass connection to functions where required. "RTMs" means "read the manuals".

Comment: The comment of Fred  ii is correctly related  to the answer .. could be a  simple image can help ..

Comment: you guys take this one, Merry Xmas ;-)

Comment: '@' to suppress error messages,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revisited the question and posted the following, seeing that nobody posted one.

- You didn't pass the db connection to `mysqli_select_db()` nor for `mysqli_query()` and need to assign a variable to the connection first.

Both of those require it in `mysqli_` and you may have been accustomed to `mysql_` in the past. MySQLi_ is different than MySQL_ when it comes to certain functions that needs a connection.

Sidenote: The `@` symbol is an error suppressor. Remove it during testing/development.

Another sidenote: Both your database and table bear the same name of `school`. Make sure that this is correct.

```
<?php 
   $servername = 'localhost';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';  
   $db='school'; 

   $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); 

   if($connect){
        echo "Connected";
   }

   else { 
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
   }

   // This isn't needed. You can pass all 4 parameters in one shot.
   // $database = mysqli_select_db($connect, $db); //or die ('not Connect to db '); 
   if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
     $sid= $_GET['sid']; 
     $sname= $_GET['sname']; 
     $fname= $_GET['fname'];
     $order= mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO school (sid,sname,fname) VALUES ('$sid','$sname','$fname');"); 
      if ($order) { 
        echo '<br>Input data is successful.';
     } else {
         // Uncomment the one below once everything is ok.
        // echo '<br>Input data is not valid.'; 

        // Comment this below once there are no errors.
        echo "There was an error: " . mysqli_error($connect);
     } 
  }
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Check for errors also via PHP and the query:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

And make sure you're running this off a webserver, or if local that PHP/MySQL are installed, running properly and using `http://localhost` as opposed to `file:///`.

Your code is also open to an SQL injection, use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Footnotes:**

You seem to want to use this in a table. `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>` if you are using those tags outside of the form which wasn't posted in your question; there are stray `<td></td>` tags.